# CASE not working as expected - Transact SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

The first Case group (Err1) in the below does not evaluate beyond the first When, unless I remove the other two Case groups, Err2 and Err3, then it works as expected. I originally had these concatenated together to create one column, but it was working as above. I thought splitting this out into separate columns would solve my problem, but no joy.

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE
       WHEN ISNULL(Approval_Date, 0) = 0 
          THEN 'Approval Date is Missing' + Char(13) + Char(13) 
          ELSE
             CASE WHEN First_Spend > (ISNULL(Approval_Date, 0) + 15)  
                     THEN 'Approval Date is too far in the past' + char(13) + Char(13) 
                  WHEN (First_Spend + 25) < ISNULL(Approval_Date, 0)  
                     THEN 'Approval Date is too far in the future' + char(13) + Char(13) 
             END
    END AS 'ERR1',
    CASE
       WHEN Funding_Status = '' 
          THEN 'Funding Status is Missing' + Char(13) + Char(13) 
    END AS 'ERR2',
    CASE
       WHEN Funding_Type = '' 
          THEN 'Funding Type is Missing' + Char(13) + Char(13) 
    END AS 'ERR3'
```

I've tried several versions of this with different, but still not correct results. Any bright ideas appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Well, the approval_date must always be `NULL` or `0`.

Comment: Do you have any sample data with expected and actual output of the query?

Comment: Have you tried adding the missing elses to the nested cases?

Comment: You do not check if First_Spend is null. Both tests inside nested case will fail if First_Spend is null.

Answer (score 1):

Your dates don't appear to be defined as dates, and, forgive me if you know this, but an empty string is not the same as null.

The example below shows what I think you want to do, but using the appropriate data-types.  I strongly recommend using the appropriate data-types.

And, to clear up any misconception, as soon as one condition in a case statement is true, no following "when" clauses are evaluated.  err1, err2 and err3 are independent case statements so they should always all be evaluated, but the nested case statement is dependent on err1.

Also, char(13) is carriage return. That will cause your output lines to be overwritten. Perhaps you want char(10) which is newline (or both if you're running on Windows).

```
create table so48010818
(
    id                int,
    approval_date     date,
    first_spend       date,
    funding_status    varchar(1),
    funding_type      varchar(1)
);

insert into so48010818 (id, approval_date, first_spend, funding_status, funding_type) values (1, null, '2017-12-28', '', '');
insert into so48010818 (id, approval_date, first_spend, funding_status, funding_type) values (2, '2017-12-20', '2017-12-28', '', '');
insert into so48010818 (id, approval_date, first_spend, funding_status, funding_type) values (3, '2017-12-12', '2017-12-28', '', '');
insert into so48010818 (id, approval_date, first_spend, funding_status, funding_type) values (4, '2017-12-27', '2017-12-01', '', '');
insert into so48010818 (id, approval_date, first_spend, funding_status, funding_type) values (5, null, '2017-12-28', null, null);
insert into so48010818 (id, approval_date, first_spend, funding_status, funding_type) values (6, '2017-12-20', '2017-12-28', null, null);
insert into so48010818 (id, approval_date, first_spend, funding_status, funding_type) values (7, '2017-12-12', '2017-12-28', null, null);
insert into so48010818 (id, approval_date, first_spend, funding_status, funding_type) values (8, '2017-12-27', '2017-12-01', null, null);
insert into so48010818 (id, approval_date, first_spend, funding_status, funding_type) values (5, null, '2017-12-28', 'X', 'Y');
insert into so48010818 (id, approval_date, first_spend, funding_status, funding_type) values (6, '2017-12-20', '2017-12-28', 'X', 'Y');
insert into so48010818 (id, approval_date, first_spend, funding_status, funding_type) values (7, '2017-12-12', '2017-12-28', 'X', 'Y');
insert into so48010818 (id, approval_date, first_spend, funding_status, funding_type) values (8, '2017-12-27', '2017-12-01', 'X', 'Y');

select * from so48010818;

select 
    id,
    approval_date,
    first_spend,
    funding_status,
    funding_type, 
    case 
        when approval_date is null then 'approval date is missing (null)'
    else               -- approval_date cannot be null here
        case
            when first_spend > dateadd(day, 15, approval_date) then 'approval date is too far in the past' 
            when dateadd(day, 25, first_spend) < approval_date then 'approval date is too far in the future'
        end
    end as 'err1',
    case 
        when funding_status is null then 'funding status is missing (null)' 
        when funding_status = '' then 'funding status is missing (empty string)' 
    end as 'err2',
    case 
        when funding_type is null then 'funding type is missing (null)' 
        when funding_type = '' then 'funding type is missing (empty string)'
    end as 'err3'
from
    so48010818;

id          approval_date    first_spend      funding_status funding_type err1                                  err2                                     err3
----------- ---------------- ---------------- -------------- ------------ ------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- -----------------------------    --------
          1             NULL       2017-12-28                             approval date is missing (null)        funding status is missing (empty string) funding type is missing (empty string)
          2       2017-12-20       2017-12-28                             NULL                                   funding status is missing (empty string) funding type is missing (empty string)
          3       2017-12-12       2017-12-28                             approval date is too far in the past   funding status is missing (empty string) funding type is missing (empty string)
          4       2017-12-27       2017-12-01                             approval date is too far in the future funding status is missing (empty string) funding type is missing (empty string)
          5             NULL       2017-12-28 NULL           NULL         approval date is missing (null)        funding status is missing (null)         funding type is missing (null)
          6       2017-12-20       2017-12-28 NULL           NULL         NULL                                   funding status is missing (null)         funding type is missing (null)
          7       2017-12-12       2017-12-28 NULL           NULL         approval date is too far in the past   funding status is missing (null)         funding type is missing (null)
          8       2017-12-27       2017-12-01 NULL           NULL         approval date is too far in the future funding status is missing (null)         funding type is missing (null)
          5             NULL       2017-12-28 X              Y            approval date is missing (null)        NULL                                     NULL
          6       2017-12-20       2017-12-28 X              Y            NULL                                   NULL                                     NULL
          7       2017-12-12       2017-12-28 X              Y            approval date is too far in the past   NULL                                     NULL
          8       2017-12-27       2017-12-01 X              Y            approval date is too far in the future NULL                                     NULL

(12 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  *, 
        CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(Approval_Date, 0) = 0 THEN 'Approval Date is Missing' + Char(13) + Char(13) 

            WHEN First_Spend > (ISNULL(Approval_Date, 0) + 15) THEN 'Approval Date is too far in the past' + char(13) + Char(13) 

            WHEN (First_Spend + 25) < ISNULL(Approval_Date, 0) THEN 'Approval Date is too far in the future' + char(13) + Char(13) 
        END AS 'ERR1',
        CASE
            WHEN Funding_Status = '' THEN 'Funding Status is Missing' + Char(13) + Char(13) 
        END AS 'ERR2',
        CASE
            WHEN Funding_Type = '' THEN 'Funding Type is Missing' + Char(13) + Char(13) 
        END AS 'ERR3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, you were all on the right track. The big issue was that some of the Cases were returning null. The original version actually worked, but it returned an error for 'Approval Date is Missing' and 'Approval Date is too far in the past', which can be the same error.

I made a few changes, I added the Elses, I played with my isnull values for Approval Date to eliminate the duplicate errors and I fixed the possibility of a missing First_Spend date. It looks like this now:

```
SELECT *, 
Case When Approval_Date is null then 'Approval Date is Missing' + Char(13) + Char(13) Else ''End +
Case When Funding_Status = '' then 'Funding Status is Missing' + Char(13) + Char(13) Else '' End +
Case When Funding_Type = '' then 'Funding Type is Missing' + Char(13) + Char(13) Else '' End +

Case 
    When ISNULL(First_Spend,0) >(isnull(Approval_Date,CAST('12/12/2099' AS DATETIME)) + 15)  then 'Approval Date is too far in the past' + char(13) + Char(13) 
    When (ISNULL(First_Spend,CAST('12/12/2099' AS DATETIME)) +25) < isnull(Approval_Date,0)  then 'Approval Date is too far in the future' + char(13) + Char(13)
    Else '' End as 'ERR'
```